# Why isn't Working? Using Hibernate and Struts 2 and getting exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I am new to hibernate and this is my second example using hibernate and Struts2, the JSP form is supposed to store the data in the database but getting the below exception.

Posting the stacktrace of the exception which comes :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
    com.InstaRecharge.hbm.UserDao.register(UserDao.java:16)
    com.InstaRecharge.action.Register.execute(Register.java:63)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:871)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1294)
    ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1370)
    ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
    ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$2.execute(OgnlUtil.java:315)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:346)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:313)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:430)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:290)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:251)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:168)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:140)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:567)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`
```

Here is Register.java

```
import com.InstaRecharge.hbm.UserDao;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.sql.*;
public class Register extends ActionSupport {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;;
    private int phone;
    private String password;
    private String repassword;

    //getter setter methods


    public String execute() throws  SQLException{

        /* ****for oracle database**** 
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");


        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","SYSTEM","SYSTEM");


        ####MySql database###
        try{Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","root","system");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into userdetail values(?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, email);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        ps.setString(3, name);
        ps.setInt(4, phone);
        int i= ps.executeUpdate();*/

        int i=UserDao.register(this);
        if(i>0){
            return SUCCESS;


        }else{
            return ERROR;
        }
    }
    String blank="Cannot be blank!!";

    public void validate(){
        int e = email.length();
        int i = email.indexOf("@");
        int d =email.indexOf(".");

        if (name.length()<1){
            addFieldError("name", blank);
        }

        if(email.length()<1){
            addFieldError("email", blank);
        }else if(i>0 && i<(e-5) && d>0 && d< (i-1) ){
            //do nothing
        }else{
            addFieldError("email", "Invalid e-mail id!!!");

        }
        if( phone < 1 ){
            addFieldError("phone", blank);
        }
        if(password.length()<1){
            addFieldError("password", blank);
        }

        if(repassword.equals(password)){
        }else{
            addFieldError("repassword", "Password did not match!");

        }
    }



}
```

This is my UserDao.java

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
public class UserDao {
public static int register(Register u){
    int i=0;
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
    t.begin();

    i=(Integer)session.save(u);
    t.commit();
    session.close();
    return i;
}
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with details in UserDao such as how are you obtaining your Hibernate session and what is your code doing inside `UserDao.register`.  Just based on what you've provided thus far, your session / entitymanager already has an active session and you're trying to start another while one is active.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Use `getCurrentSession` instead of opening session each time.

Comment: Same exception again after using `getCurrentSession`

Comment: Don't create a new SessionFactory every time. the application should create a sessionfactory only on startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a basic flaw in the code as suggested by Nathan Hughes and I am just going to elaborate it.

The session you are trying to create is with the help of sessionfactory. Now since you are trying to create a sessionfactory everytime, there is a possibility of threads accessing transactions which are already started by previous thread. This is violation of ACID property for a transaction.

The simplest solution is to have a static class level sessionfactory which will return sessionfactory only once in an application's lifetime .

```
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    public class UserDao {
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    public static int register(Register u){
        int i=0;

        factory = getSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        t.begin();

        i=(Integer)session.save(u);
        t.commit();
        session.close();
        return i;
    }



public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        if(factory==null)
         factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

        return factory;
    }
  }
```

Although this is very basic solution, I will suggest to handle the transactions using standard JEE annotations or Spring's transaction Management annotations.

Comment: Thanks, what worked for me is i removed the `t.bigin()`